# Redirect after Jquery AJAX call giving Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

After doing an AJAX call, am redirecting- using the following code. But, after AJAX completion, it gives Error alert; then its redirecting.

```
callService($serviceUrl, $serviceName, 'POST');             
//redirecting to nextpage
window.location.href = "nextPage.html";

function callService($serviceUrl, $serviceName, $method) {
  ......

  $.ajax({
    url : $serviceUrl,
    dataType : "json",
    type : $method,
    data : $requestData,
    success : function (data) {
        switch($serviceName) {
            case 'getTopRated':     populateTopRated(data);
                        break;
            case 'GetLatestScoop':  populateLiveScoop(data);
                        break;
            .....
        }
        $.mobile.pageLoading(true);
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error");
        $.mobile.pageLoading(true);
    }
  });

}
```

Is there a way to resolve it without- modifying the function?

Comment: Your error handler is being called. Can you specify what the error is by looking at the textStatus and errorThrown fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait until the `ajax` request complete before you redirect to another page. Since you redirect as soon as calling the `service` the `request` `aborts` and then `error` handler is triggered due to which you are seeing the `alert` message from error handler. Move the code to redirect inside `ajax` `success` callback it will work.

```
function callService($serviceUrl, $serviceName, $method) {
  ......

  $.ajax({
    url : $serviceUrl,
    dataType : "json",
    type : $method,
    data : $requestData,
    success : function (data) {
        switch($serviceName) {
            case 'getTopRated':     populateTopRated(data);
                        break;
            case 'GetLatestScoop':  populateLiveScoop(data);
                        break;
            .....


            //redirecting to nextpage
            window.location.href = "nextPage.html";
        }
        $.mobile.pageLoading(true);
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error");
        $.mobile.pageLoading(true);
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: +1, pretty much what I was going to say after I scratched my head trying to make sense of the intent. :), one thought was: if you are redirecting anyway, why do the ajax at all>?

Comment: we can also redirect from complete: . But, is there no other way without making the function callService()
changes!

Comment: Nope, you have to handle it inside `callService` method only.